# Trouble Importing Using Unittest Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-unittest

I'm trying to play around with the `unittest` module so that I can become more familiar with the process of running tests but I'm hitting an error when running the tests on another file. I'm getting an invalid syntax error on the following line,

```
from AccuAdmin2.0 import format_filename
```

Apparently it doesn't like the `0`. Without renaming my file, how can I get around this?

My code:

```
import unittest
from AccuAdmin2.0 import format_filename

class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def testSomething(self):
        self.assertTrue(format_filename("fehfihehe_efeaf"))
```

Here is the entire error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 120, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 41, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = methods.load()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1572, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/accudeveloper/PycharmProjects/AccuAdmin2.0/AccuAdmin2.0 UnitTests.py", line 3
    from AccuAdmin2.0 import format_filename
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `AccuAdmin2.0` wouid be the `0` submodule of the `AccuAdmin2` package, and `0` isn't a valid module name. *"Without renaming my file how can I get around this?"* - you can't.

Comment: So moral of the story, avoid periods in files.

Comment: Yes, particularly for Python scripts/modules - stick to valid identifiers.